# Batch operation with item list using reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following form:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9cu3.png)

It contains three item lists (red bordered), and many item elements (green bordered). Each item list provide batch operations for the items selected by checkbox. Easy right? Ok. I get back-end data and create ReactiveForm structure, then bind these FormControls to the components. When form changes (valueChanges event) I keep the data to back-end. Questions:

Is the selection flag should be part of ReactiveForm structure? If Yes, I will get valueChanges event on each checkbox toggle. I of course can filter selection changes and compare the data without selection flag with the previous one, but I fill it is not so good solution.

Because selection flag has meaning only between 'item' and 'item list' may I create selection flag separately from main ReactiveForm inside 'item list' component? What should it be template driven? reactive forms? But in this case I should always keep in sync port list and selection list, looks also not so good.

Thanks a lot.